# Which functions in Lua would one use to map or project an image onto the surface of a sphere?

Tags: lua, geometry, projection, map-projections

I'm in the process of using Lua to create a spherical attitude and heading indicator (one could say it is similar to the [ksp navball](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Navball)! ) for a project I'm working on. How would I project an image onto the surface of the sphere/ball? The ball should be able to rotate about 3 axes with full freedom.

I've tried researching and figuring this out for the past few days, but to no avail. The method of projection isn't critical, as long as the image retains its shape (so perhaps the [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) could work).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please explain the context; Do you want to convert coordinates? Or do you want to render a textured sphere?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I'm brand new to scripting in Lua. I would like to render a textured sphere.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be specific to Lua at all; the methods of rendering a textured sphere are pretty much universal across tools and languages. Why don't you just google for "how to draw a textured sphere" and go from there?